# Mapper.Map EnderecoViewModel.CidadeViewModel Endereco.Cidade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda, ddd

Tenho a class **Endereco**

```
public class Endereco
{
 public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
 public int CidadeId { get; set; }
}
```

E tenho a ViewModel Dessa Class:

```
  public class EnderecoViewModel
{
public virtual CidadeViewModel CidadeViewModel { get; set; }
        public int CidadeId { get; set; }
}
```

Minha classe Endereço, tem uma Cidade.
Na minha controller, tenho uma Query assim:

```
 var end = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Endereco>, IEnumerable<EnderecoViewModel>>(_EnderecoServico.BuscarPorIdDoCliente(id));
```

Essa consulta me trás os endereços Do Cliente.
O problema está na Endereco.Cidade, que está vindo Null.
o Endereco.CidadeId está vindo corretamente.como eu faço esse mapeamento usando o Mapper? se eu estanciar a entidade, e atribuir seus valores: `entidadeViewModel.CidadeViewModel.Nome = entidade.Cidade.Nome`, funciona, mas como eu faço isso com o Mapper?

Essa é a consulta na Camada Data.Repositorio:

```
public class EnderecoRepositorio : RepositorioBase<Endereco>, IEnderecoRepositorio
    {
        public IEnumerable<Endereco> BuscarPorIdDoCliente(int? id)
        {
            return db.EnderecoDb.Where(e => e.ClienteId == id);
        }
    }
```

Class Configuração Mapper:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile: Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<CidadeViewModel, Cidade>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ComplementoPessoaFisicaViewModel, ComplementoPessoaFisica>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ContadorViewModel, Contador>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ContatoViewModel, Contato>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ControleDeCobrancaViewModel, ControleDeCobranca>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ControleDeVencimentoViewModel, ControleDeVencimento>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ConveniadosViewModel, Conveniados>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EnderecoViewModel, Endereco>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ParceiroComercialViewModel, ParceiroComercial>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<RamoDeAtividadeViewModel, RamoDeAtividade>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<RegistroDeBloqueiosViewModel, RegistroDeBloqueios>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<TipoDeSistemasViewModel, TipoDeSistemas>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>();
        }
    }
```

Proxima

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "DomainToViewModelMappingProfile"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Cidade, CidadeViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ComplementoPessoaFisica, ComplementoPessoaFisicaViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Contador, ContadorViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Contato, ContatoViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ControleDeCobranca, ControleDeCobrancaViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ControleDeVencimento, ControleDeVencimentoViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Conveniados, ConveniadosViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ParceiroComercial, ParceiroComercialViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<RamoDeAtividade, RamoDeAtividadeViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<RegistroDeBloqueios, RegistroDeBloqueiosViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<TipoDeSistemas, TipoDeSistemasViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Eu depurei o cód, e percebi, que na consulta, na camada repositório, ele esta trazendo a **CIDADE**, Só não está transformando esse Endereco.Cidade em EnderecoVireModel.CidadeViewModel... há algum mapeando que deva ser feito??

Comment: Você mapeou as classes Cidade e CidadeViewModel? `CreateMap<Cidade, CidadeViewModel>().ReverseMap();`

Comment: Só fiz o mapeamento `var end = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Endereco>, IEnumerable<EnderecoViewModel>>(_EnderecoServico.BuscarPorIdDoCliente(id));` como que eu faço esse `CreateMap<Cidade, CidadeViewModel>().ReverseMap();`, é na controller msm??

Comment: Você cria uma classe de configuração para registrar o AutoMapper e registra essa classe global. Seu projeto é ASP.NET MVC Core? Vou postar as duas maneiras de registar esta classe de configuração do AutoMapper.

Comment: Eu já tinha feito isso.. mas graças a vc, eu fui olhar novamente, e acho que encontrei o erro.... na minha class `DomainToViewModelMappingProfile`, o `ProfileName` ta assim: `get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile"; }` e na `ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile` ta do mesmo jeito --- > `get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappingToProfile"; }`

Comment: Na, vdd, continua do msm jeito, o `EnderecoViewModel.CidadeViewModel` continua vindo null

Comment: Você pode colocar a classe de configuração na pergunta? Está faltando alguma coisa...A classe Cidade tem propriedades iguais as da viewModel? Manda essas classes também, por favor.

Comment: Coloquei ai as class na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O AutoMapper não está conseguindo converter a `Cidade` por que na classe `EnderecoViewModel` a propriedade está como `CidadeViewModel` ao invés de `Cidade`.

```
  public class EnderecoViewModel
{
    public virtual CidadeViewModel Cidade { get; set; }
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }

}

 public class Endereco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo... é a primeira vez que trabalho com AutoMapper.. obrigado pela força!

Comment: Por nada @RafaelPassos Depois que eu copiei as classes aqui, que fui ver que era o nome da propriedade. Valeu!